# How to catch part of url string in php

Tags: php

I have following URL string:

```
http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/dir
```

How can I bind everything after the **`=`** to a php variable?

so my variable should contain:

```
$String = 'uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/dir'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use explode to get part after =

```
$str = "http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/dir";

$strArr = explode("=",$str);
$url = $strArr[1];
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible solution, would be to use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/dir';

$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($query_string, $query_vars);

var_dump($query_vars);
```

It’ll give you an array with all the GET parameters the URL might contain.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$parts = parse_url('http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/dir');

parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['dir'];
```